# How do I make this parallel bash script more efficient?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, io, gnu-parallel

I have a simple script involving afni command line tools that I am running in parallel from bash, but it is very disk I/O intensive and slows things down on our server (using only 2-3 out of the total 96 cores) despite only running a few jobs at a time. The most jobs I am able to run at a time without slowing things down and increasing iowait is 2. I feel like it may have something to do with the fact that it is writing so many files, but I haven't found a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash 

task() {
x=$1
SUB_stats="path/to/subject/data/"$x"_cond3.feat/stats/"

cd $SUB_stats

3dcalc -prefix precentral_top_N_voxels_b -a Precentral_b+orig -b T_top_N_voxels_precentral+orig -expr 'a*b'

3dcalc -prefix occipital_top_N_voxels_b -a Occipital_b+orig -b T_top_N_voxels_occipital+orig -expr 'a*b'

3dcalc -prefix temporal_top_N_voxels_b -a Temporal_b+orig -b T_top_N_voxels_temporal+orig -expr 'a*b'


3dmaskave -quiet -sigma precentral_top_N_voxels_b+orig[0..390] > avgroi_precentral_subbrik_topvoxels.txt

3dmaskave -quiet -sigma occipital_top_N_voxels_b+orig[0..390] > avgroi_occipital_subbrik_topvoxels.txt

3dmaskave -quiet -sigma temporal_top_N_voxels_b+orig[0..390] > avgroi_temporal_subbrik_topvoxels.txt

} 

export -f task
cat young_fsf.txt | parallel --nice 15 --progress --eta -j 2 task
```

Comment: It seems to me like you've led us to proposed answers, none of which are shell scripts. If the processes are I/O intensive and you know that the processes write lots of files, what do you imagine a solution to be? Force the processes to write to /dev/null? Buy faster disk?

Comment: Sorry, I am still pretty novice and this is my first time asking a question here. I was wondering if the way I am writing the script is inefficient. For example, should I be splitting up each of these lines into separate scripts for example? Is there something better for I/O intensive processes than this function format?